# Excel Error: Removed Records - Graphs removed after uploading data from R

Tags: r

I have a relatively small database in excel and then I update it with the following code:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyr)

Basetotal<- read.csv("C:/Users/tuv_1/Desktop/Copia CA/Coronavirus/Global_Mobility_Report.csv")
attach(Basetotal)

Datos<-Basetotal %>% filter(sub_region_1 == "", metro_area == "") %>% pivot_wider(
    id_cols = date, 
    names_from = country_region, 
    values_from = c(transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline, workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline))

Datos <- Datos[,c("date","transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline_Colombia","transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline_Costa Rica","transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline_El Salvador","transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline_Honduras","transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline_Panama","workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline_Colombia","workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline_Costa Rica","workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline_El Salvador","workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline_Honduras","workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline_Panama")]
colnames(Datos) <- c("Fecha","Colombia","Costa Rica","El Salvador","Honduras","Panamá","Colombia","Costa Rica","El Salvador","Honduras","Panamá")
Datos$Fecha<-as.Date(Datos$Fecha)


wb <- loadWorkbook("Global Mobility.xlsx")
writeData(wb, sheet = "Datos", Datos, startRow = 2 ,colNames = T, rowNames = F)
saveWorkbook(wb,"Global Mobility.xlsx",overwrite = T)
```

Initially, I have 4 sheets (tabs) in my file, one where I upload my data, the second one is a formulated tab that uses information from the first one, the third and fourth ones are graphs. And after I run the code, the information is uploaded ant this error appears:

Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content:
Removed Records: Part /xl/drawings/drawing3.xml. (Drawing way)
Removed Records: Part /xl/drawings/drawing4.xml. (Drawing way)

And then after I click Accept, the graphs I had, disappear. What could be causing this? I'm desperate with this, please help

Comment: Once the file is updated are the worksheet names and the cell references the same? My guess would be that R destroys the data/links somehow causing the graphs to disappear.

Comment: Not at all, the names are different before and after updating

Comment: Does the data that drives the graphs still exist?

Comment: Yes, before and after the uploading, the data remains. So, the data that I upload goes into the first tab only, the second tab drags data from that first tab, and the third and fourth tabs are graphs that use the data in that second tab. After I run my code and open the file, only the third and fourth tabs (the graphs) disappear

Comment: Try the create = TRUE option on the load workbook function? It seems to me like it's replacing the entire workbook, not just the sheets for some reason.